# I'm not sure how to insert "path to this file" in a source command. I want to forward source commands without using a hardcoded fully qualified path

Tags: bash, zsh

What I'm trying to do should be simple. Yet it's just not working.

I have a repo with my dot files. I want to be able to clone this repo anywhere in my system, and just source one single file. I then want that file to source other files, as required, using a relative path. Because I don't want to force you to clone this repo somewhere specifically and hardcode all my paths. Reasonable, I hope.

Thus, my repo has this simple file structure

```
.dot-files/
├─ bash/
│  ├─ default-config
│  ├─ .bunch_of_dot_files
├─ zsh/
│  ├─ default-config
│  ├─ .bunch_of_dot_files
```

I then want my default-config to source those dot files, no matter how they look. Today, they are in the same exact folder. Tomorrow they may be in different subfolders, idk.

And it is a hard requirement, that the originating `.bashrc`, or `.zshrc` or `.whateverRC` do not know the structure of this repos. They should just source a config, and NOTHING else.

But, for the sake of argument, a complete list of how it is right now:

## ZSH

```
$ cd ~/.dot-files/zsh/
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  7 me  staff    224 May  8 13:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 me  staff    224 May  8 13:00 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   1423 May  8 12:32 .alias
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  18582 May  8 12:32 .git-prompt.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   2059 May  8 12:32 .prompt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff    926 May  8 14:01 .zsh-git-info
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff    143 May  8 15:02 default-config
```

$ cat ~/.zshrc

```bash
source ~/.dot-files/zsh/default-config
```

$ cat ~/.dot-files/zsh/default-config

```bash
source "$(dirname "$0")/.alias"
source "$(dirname "$0")/.prompt"
source "$(dirname "$0")/.zsh-git-info"
source "$(dirname "$0")/.git-prompt.sh"
```

This does work, perfectly.

## BASH

```
$ cd ~/.dot-files/bash/
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  8 me  staff    256 May  8 13:28 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 me  staff    224 May  8 13:00 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   1791 May  8 13:08 .alias
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  79837 Apr 12  2022 .git-completion.bash
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   1602 May  8 13:49 .git-prompt
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   1816 May  8 13:06 .ps1
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff    877 May  8 13:09 .utils
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff    142 May  8 15:20 default-config
```

$ cat ~/.bashrc

```bash
source ~/.dot-files/bash/default-config
```

$ cat ~/.dot-files/bash/default-config

```bash
source "$(dirname -- "$0")/.git-prompt"
source "$(dirname -- "$0")/.ps1"
source "$(dirname -- "$0")/.alias"
source "$(dirname -- "$0")/.utils"
```

This does not work

```
-bash: ./.git-prompt: No such file or directory
-bash: ./.ps1: No such file or directory
-bash: ./.alias: No such file or directory
-bash: ./.utils: No such file or directory
```

## What I'm trying to do

I want to change my shell `chsh -s /bin/bash`, restart terminal. And I expect it to just work.

I want anyone can clone wherever they want.

I want people to just point towards that default-config for each shell, in their `.bashrc` and `.zshrc`.

I want that repo's default-config to reference relative path to where the it itself is. I want to NEVER have a hardcoded full path.

For zsh, `source "$(dirname "$0")` just works. The steps as I understand them:

- `~/.zshrc` calls source on a file directly: `~/.dot-files/zsh/default-config`
- said file calls source command, yes, but it inserts "path to me" with `$(dirname "$0")` followed by the name of a file in the same folder as "me".

  - `source "$(dirname "$0")/.alias"` transforms to `source ~/.dot-files/zsh/.alias`

Bash does not work, no idea why. What else could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bash, use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`. (It's an array that contains the entire "stack" of files being read, but the 0th array element can also be accessed as just `$BASH_SOURCE`.)

For example:

```
. "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}/.alias"
```

Comment: Okay, this worked. I'm just a bit confused on what exactly is happening here. Using just ${BASH_SOURCE} gives me a full path including the current file as a folder. It tries to go one level too deep (in a file). I get that this somehow removes the last step (current file) from that. But I don't understand what `[0]%/*` is saying.

Comment: `[0]` selects the 0th array element, containing a path to the script, while `%/*` removes the file name (i.e. the part that would match `/*`) from the end. The difference between array and non-array variable access is only the `[0]`, _not_ the whole `[0]%/*`.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think I understand. This works perfectly. Thanks.